# Using MixPanel alias in Facebook and Google login

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-api, mixpanel

I'm implementing MixPanel Profile identification in a web app which implements Facebook and Google login. According to the following link [how should I handle my user identity with the mixpanel javascript](https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-should-i-handle-my-user-identity-with-the-mixpanel-javascript-library) the `.alias()` method has to be called only once in the during the signup procedure. During the login procedure we need to call identify. My problem come when I have Facebook and Google login. In that case there is no signup procedure. So when the auth return successfully, what should I use? `alias()` or `identify()`?